# Problematic tag: [segmentation]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-deletion

The SO tag [segmentation](/questions/tagged/segmentation) is a bit problematic: it is associated with two **completely different** concepts:

1. [image-segmentation](/questions/tagged/image-segmentation)
2. [segmentation-fault](/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault)

Is it possible to completely remove the *segmentation* tag? and prevent it from being used?

Right now this ambiguous *segmentation* tag causes questions regarding image processing to be linked and associated with topics regarding memory issues (and vice versa).

**UPDATE:**

[segmentation](/questions/tagged/segmentation) was removed from all questions, and was replaced by more discriminative tags: [segmentation-fault](/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault), [image-segmentation](/questions/tagged/image-segmentation), [memory-segmentation](/questions/tagged/memory-segmentation) and [text-segmentation](/questions/tagged/text-segmentation).

Thanks to all users who participated in this small clean-up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Wikipedia reports, *segmentation* can have more than one meaning, in computing:

- Image segmentation
- Memory segmentation
- Packet segmentation
- Speech segmentation
- Text segmentation

[segmentation](/questions/tagged/segmentation) should be replaced from a more appropriate tag, which avoids any ambiguity, such as [text-segmentation](/questions/tagged/text-segmentation), for which there are already questions, [speech-segmentation](/questions/tagged/speech-segmentation), and [memory-fragmentation](/questions/tagged/memory-fragmentation).

Once the questions are retagged, we can consider if requesting [segmentation](/questions/tagged/segmentation) to be burninated. I would avoid making it a synonym of another tag, as this would mean to give a preference to a tag over other tags.

Comment: I just wrote the excerpt [tag:segmetation] (it was empty) I made it synonym to [tag:image-segmentation]. It may be the case that I did wrong... I want to use this meta question to resolve this issue.

Comment: @madth3 I didn't notice the OP wrote the tag wiki before to ask this question. I thought the tag was used already with that purpose.

Comment: I removed all questions tagged [tag:segmentation]. Can you **burninate** this tag now? -- Thanks!

Comment: Burninating a tag means removing it from the history of every question using it; once a tag is burninated, it is like the tag has never been used. As you removed the tag from all the questions, there is no need to burninate it, as the tag will be deleted between 24 hours. Burninating is done to avoid editing every single question.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent this tag from being re-created in the future?

Comment: It is possible, but that it is done when the tag keeps being used when it should not be used. Community Coordinators do that when it is strictly necessary, and when there is consensus about the tag being very bad. In short, if the tag can simply be removed from the questions using it, the tag is not black-listed; if it is not possible to remove it because for each X questions that gets it removed there are Y questions getting the tag, then the tag could be black-listed.

Comment: So, now that there are no question with this tag the subject is closed?

Comment: Until somebody else doesn't start using again [tag:segmentation], and it is impossible to remove it from the questions, the topic is closed. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

There's a bunch of questions tagged [segmentation](/questions/tagged/segmentation) which have nothing to do with either images or segmentation faults. In fact, the highest-voted question in the tag is about text processing:

- [How to split a string into words. Ex: "stringintowords" -> "String Into Words"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3466972/209139)
- [Is there any good open-source or freely available Chinese segmentation algorithm available?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5834371/209139)

And then there's this, about managing datasets:

- [Merging approximately equal points in dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9221878/209139)
- [Can I track multiple Google Analytics events at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9572402/209139)

Segmenting voices:

- [Segmentation of a voice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8171947/209139)

And stuff about memory segments, but not about segmentation *faults*, specifically:

- [Why does Linux on x86 use different segments for user processes and the kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4575032/209139)
- [How to use a logical address in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10354063/209139)
- [How does x86 real-mode segments overlap help memory saving?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8728220/209139)
- [Memory segmentation in modern operating systems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9458436/209139)
- [How is a program segmented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10360844/209139)

So what we currently have is a certain amount of confusion.

Comment: I agree with your **confusion** conclusion. My question: how can we proceed?

Comment: @Shai, [retag *all* the questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=clean+all+the+things)!

Comment: I'm working on it... But as it seems [tag:segmentation-falut] and [tag:image-segmentation] does not cover all the cases...